# Is this proof of uniqueness of the limit correct?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

I've tried to show the following: let $(M,d_M)$ and $(N,d_N)$ be metric spaces and $f : M \to N$. If $a \in M$ and $\lim_{p\to a}f(p)$ exists, then it is unique.

I'm a little unsure if the proof is correct, mainly the use of the squeeze theorem in the end. Is this proof a good one?

My proof was as follows: suppose there were two limits, $L_1$ and $L_2$, then by the definition, given $\epsilon/2 > 0$ there would be $\delta_1 > 0$ and $\delta_2 > 0$ such that if we take $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, then this means that $d_M(p,a) < \delta$ implies $d_N(f(p),L_1)<\epsilon/2$ and at the same time $d_N(f(p),L_2)<\epsilon/2$.

Now, summing these two inequalities, we have $d_N(f(p),L_1)+d_N(f(p),L_2)<\epsilon$, but $d_N(f(p),L_1)=d(L_1,f(p))$ and thus $d_N(L_1,f(p))+d_N(f(p),L_2)<\epsilon$, now since we have triangle inequality available, we have $d_N(L_1,L_2)\leq d_N(L_1, f(p))+d_N(f(p),L_2)<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ and since $d_N$ is metric, we now have that $-\epsilon < d_N(L_1,L_2)<\epsilon$ and then if we define $\phi_1,\phi,\phi_2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\phi_1(\epsilon)=-\epsilon$, $\phi(\epsilon)=d_N(L_1,L_2)$ and $\phi_2(\epsilon)=\epsilon$ we found out that in reality we have:

$$\phi_1(\epsilon) < \phi(\epsilon) < \phi_2(\epsilon)$$

Now taking the limit in $\mathbb{R}$ when $\epsilon$ goes to zero, $\phi_1(\epsilon)$ and $\phi_2(\epsilon)$ goes to zero, and so the limit of $\phi(\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ going to zero, must be zero. But since $\phi$ independs on $\epsilon$ this implies that $\phi = 0$ and so $d_N(L_1,L_2) = 0$ implying by properties of metric that $L_1 = L_2$.

I felt this proof too simple, so I'm almost certain there is some little detail I forgot about. Is it correct?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: This proof appears to be correct. However, you don't actually need to define any functions or use the squeeze theorem. If you assume $L_1 \neq L_2$ and take $\epsilon$ to be $d_N(L_1, L_2)$ you produce a contradiction.

Comment: That's true @AGM, I've tried it now and the proof is much quicker. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You seem to prety much have it. I would probably start with $d_N(L_1,L_2)$ and then use the triangle inequality to involve the $d_N(L_i,f(p))$. Once you have the distance between the limits trapped between $\pm \epsilon$ you're done. Let $\epsilon$ go to zero. There's no problem since the distance between the limits is independent of $\epsilon$. You could always take the slick road. Metric spaces are Hausdorff and limits are unique in Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: You don't include the hypothesis that $a$ is a limit point of $M$.  Without this, either the limit at $a$ is undefined, or if you carry over the rest of the definition verbatim, the result is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, but the style is not the best.
When you have shown that $\;d_N(L_1,L_2)<\epsilon$, you are done because $\;d_N(L_1,L_2) \ge 0$.
Remember the proposition:

> If $\; 0 \le a < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, then $a=0$.

You see this in the proof of a Master:

J.Dieudonné *Foundations of Modern Analysis* (1960), prop. (3.13.3) pag. 47.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems correct. You could proceed quicker though.

Suppose not. Then there are two limits $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$. Take $0<\epsilon=d_{N}(L_{1},L_{2})$. By the definition of limit there is $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ such that if $d_{M}(p,a)<\delta_{1}$ then $d_{N}(f(p),L_{1})<\frac{\epsilon}{100}$ and if $d_{M}(p,a)<\delta_{2}$ then $d_{N}(f(p),L_{2})<\frac{\epsilon}{100}$. Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$. Then if $d_{M}(p,a)<\delta$ then $d_{N}(L_{1},L_{2})\le d_{N}(L_{1},f(p))+d_{N}(f(p),L_{2})<\frac{\epsilon}{100}+\frac{\epsilon}{100}=\frac{\epsilon}{50}=\frac{1}{50}d_{N}(L_{1},L_{2})$. So $49d_{N}(L_{1},L_{2})<0$ which is impossible.